# "Message was missing required fields" error thrown by OpenGL Tracer

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to debug a problem in my OpenGL application and wanted to use the Android OpenGL Tracer to look at it in detail. The Tracer seems to work fine initially and collects some data, but when I try to open the trace file I get the following error:

> Error parsing OpenGL Trace File
>
> Message was missing required fields. (Lite runtime could not determine which fields were missing).

This only happens for this specific application, and not for other ones. The big difference is that this application uses OpenGL ES 3.

Is there a general problem with the tracer and OpenGL ES 3.0? Are there any workarounds for this error?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm getting the same problem with ES 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this error myself and found a solution.  In your AndroidManifest.xml use a version of the following tag:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true"/>
```

My version looks like this (with a note to remember):

```
<!-- Tell the system this app requires OpenGL ES 3.1. -->
<!-- NOTE: This must be correct for the OpenGL ES Tracer to work properly -->
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030001" android:required="true"/>
```

See the official documentation page for reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#manifest

This page also has further details about the value:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

> ANDROID:GLESVERSION
>   The OpenGL ES version required by the application. The higher 16 bits represent the major number and the lower 16 bits represent the minor number. For example, to specify OpenGL ES version 2.0, you would set the value as "0x00020000", or to specify OpenGL ES 3.2, you would set the value as "0x00030002".

Comment: Nevermind this.  I still get the error with longer traces.